# Restart event log after installing source and log

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer

I am using Wix and installing an event log like:

```
<util:EventSource Log='MyLogName' Name='MyLogSource' EventMessageFile='%systemroot%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\EventLogMessages.dll' />
```

I have a service that runs and tries to log to MyLogSource after installation. It does not begin to log unless I restart my system.

However, if I create the log in C# code, I can immediately log. The C# code can be in my service OnStart()

```
EventLog.CreateEventSource("MyLogSouce", "MyLogName");
```

I have a Systems.Diagnostics.EventLog instance named eventLog in my service class that is initialized like:

```
eventLog .Source = "MyLogSource"; // instance variable created in InitializeComponent()
```

To clarify, if I use Wix to create the event source (and therefore don't use the C# code to create it), then when the service starts and starts logging, nothing goes in the log. I have to reboot and then everything works.

However, if I comment out the Wix part to create the event source and do it in C# code, then when I start logging, the data goes in the log and no restart is necessary. My service does not really depend on any other services.

Is there some kind of trick to get it to work immediately if I install using Wix? Is there some way to use a `<ServiceControl />` entry for my component so that I can restart or stop and start a service so that logging works without rebooting?

Update: 28 Oct 2021

I did go digging through the EventLog source code. It does not restart any services. However, it creates two event sources when creating an event source. When creating an Event source from WiX, it just creates the one event source.

So in Wix if I'm creating MyLogSource and MyLogName, it creates just the registry entries for those items.However, in the C# source code when calling the EventLog.CreateEventSource API, with the same arguments, it does create those items, however, it also creates another event source named MyEventLog.

So, in the registry tree, there is the event log MyEventLog, but under the key are the two event sources MyEventSource *and* MyEventLog.

Comment: I did a clean up my registry and any old .evtx files that might have been hanging around. After doing that with several reboots necessary because of locks on files, etc, I finally got to a relatively clean event log setup (after having previously uninstalled my service). When I installed my service, it logged just fine after installation without requiring a restart. I can only surmise that I had some residuals or artifacts from previous tries that were causing the problems.

Comment: I've never seen this behavior. I've always been able to write to an Eventlog log/source as soon as I created it.

Comment: Good debugging Joseph. Bring out your virtual machines to get a clean slate. I hate them for many reasons - primarily maintenance and other clunk - but it is the best way to get things properly tested. Beware of the common virtual machine issues of missing, basic runtimes and such things. Other than that: virtuals will save the day (and could recover malware that has been persisted in the image - repeated repeatedly in a tautological fashion - always something).